# background transition flash when mouse leave target

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate background property using transition.

When I hover over target it works smooth but when I leave out it makes like flash!

Shouldn't it be smooth in and out?

It looks that mix-blend-mode behind this flashing issue or maybe sth else so I need explanation.

```css
a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

img {
    position:relative;
    width: 172px;
    border-radius:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
    
a::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 172px;
    height: 242px;
    background: #2d293e;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 14px;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out,background 400ms ease-in-out;
}

a:hover::after {
    background:#FF0101;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

```html
<a>
    <img src="https://images.wikidi.net/crop/172x242/http://f2.fsm.wikidi.com/af/ad/yb/e0d20df22741de9c3480e691bc7a3a41efceddcd.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Comment: Is there a particular effect you want to achieve by having different times on both transitions? For me it works fine, but I am not sure when you are getting the flash you are saying.

Comment: No, I tried to slow down the background speed because I thought it may be the reason but it isn't , The flash happened when leave ... first it goes smooth but it makes red flash in the end

Comment: You should give the same transition for `opacity` and `background`.  when the transitions take different amount of time, the animation is not symmetric for the transition in and out

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky did you tested your assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is to do with timing. This line in particular:

```
transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out,background 400ms ease-in-out;
```

the opacity only lasts 300ms, and then for 100ms the background transition continues but the opacity transition has stopped.

This means that if you want the exact opposite to happen, you want the opacity to be delayed 100ms before it begins to transition for 300ms.

To do this, you just need to add the following in then `a::after` css, and keep the above line in the `a:hover::after` definition:

```
transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 100ms,background 400ms ease-in-out;
```

(the 100 ms after ease-in-out for the opacity transition in shorthand for a 100ms delay).

then the transition looks the same going in and going out. See the snippet:

```css
a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

img {
    position:relative;
    width: 172px;
    border-radius:15px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
    
a::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 172px;
    height: 242px;
    background: #2d293e;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 14px;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out 100ms,background 400ms ease-in-out;
}

a:hover::after {
    background:#FF0101;
    opacity:0.1;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out,background 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a>
    <img src="https://images.wikidi.net/crop/172x242/http://f2.fsm.wikidi.com/af/ad/yb/e0d20df22741de9c3480e691bc7a3a41efceddcd.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a different transition for the mouse-in and the mouse-out then you will have a better control and you can avoid the flash

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 172px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

a::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 172px;
  height: 242px;
  background: #2d293e;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 14px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transition: opacity 400ms  ease-in, background 250ms  ease-in;
}

a:hover::after {
  background: #FF0101;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in, background 400ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://images.wikidi.net/crop/172x242/http://f2.fsm.wikidi.com/af/ad/yb/e0d20df22741de9c3480e691bc7a3a41efceddcd.jpg" >
</a>
```

Comment: did you use `ease-in` on purpose? imho `ease-in-out` in all places looks better

Comment: @AleksandrBelugin there is no particular reason, I simply focused on the main idea which is to use different transition then it's up to the OP to adjust anyone like they want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting your background in the a:hover:after causes the flash, it's adjusting to that too quickly. Try removing it and seeing if the result is ok.

Comment: I thought that but if you agree with me the speed applied `in` and `out` and this means - if the speed the main reason - flashing  will reproduce on `in state` not just `out state`